# Set a new value for $key => $value using WordPress shortcode_atts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to change a value in a $key => $value pair but I can't seem to get it working.

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            "type"     => FALSE,
            "size"     => FALSE
        ), $atts );


print_r($atts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [type] => default
    [size] => default
)
```

```
if ( $atts['size'] == 'default' ) {
    $atts['size'] == false;
}

print_r($atts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [type] => default
    [size] => default
)
```

Basically, what I want to do is, if "size" is "default", then reset the value to false or an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assigned the variable! See:

```
$atts['size'] == false;
            //^^ See here, you don't assign anything
```

You have to remove one `=` so it looks like this:

```
$atts['size'] = false;
```

Also i would use `var_dump` here, because if you assign false and you use `print_r` the output would be:

```
Array ( [type] => default [size] => )
```

With `var_dump` you see it better:

```
array(2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "default" ["size"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: OMG, I'm such a fool. I don't know how I didn't see that. Thank you!!